# Unable to login Twitch TV via script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, twitch

I am trying to login to Twitch.tv website via Python. Despite of giving all parameters it's still not letting me to log in. Below is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

# #user[login]:volatil3_
# user[password]:thisispassword
#https://secure.twitch.tv/user/login
# <a href="#" class="header_nick button drop" id="user_display_name"> volatil3_ </a>


def connect():
    user = {'Username':'volatil3_','Password':'thisispassword'}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36','Referer':'http://www.twitch.tv/user/login'}

    with requests.Session() as s:
        html = s.get("http://www.twitch.tv/user/login", headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)
        tokenTag = soup.find("input", {"name" : "authenticity_token"})
        token = tokenTag["value"].strip()
        #print(html.text)
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
        credentials = {"user[login]":'volatil3_', "user[password]":'thisispassword',"authenticity_token":token,'redirect_on_login':'https://secure.twitch.tv/user/login','embed_form':'false','utf8':'&#x2713;','mp_source_action':'','follow':''}
        print(credentials)
        s.post("https://secure.twitch.tv/user/login", data = credentials, headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=10,allow_redirects=True)
        #html = s.get("http://www.twitch.tv", headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)
        logginTag = soup.find("a", {"id" : "user_display_name"})
        print(logginTag)
        if "Log In" in html.text:
            print("cound not log in")
connect()
```

Ideally after login it should get back to home page and show name of Logged IN user. For me it's shows html that indicates it is not logged in. Help me please

The user/password given here are Real and can be used for testing

Comment: first of all.. looks like variable `html` only contains the old html.. and I don't think after you login the new html will be stored in there. i.e. even if your post works, and you logged in, you can access the new html by called `result = s.post(..)` `newhtml = request._content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at the site you want and found it to be really heavy javascript. After the login post request, it will follow a redirect, and in the new page, most of the contents are generated by Javascript which is really a hassle to work with either using request, urllib2, ..etc... Seems like you are only at stage1: login, after that, probably tons of work really cannot not be guaranteed without using a Javascript engine like PhantomJS, [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html). Here is a POC that I wrote using Selenium in Python. Hope will be helpful.

To install Selenium:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Here is a Python solution using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_username = "volatil3_"
my_password = "thisispassword"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.twitch.tv/user/login")
elem_user = driver.find_element_by_id("login_user_login")
elem_passwd = driver.find_element_by_id("user[password]")
elem_user.send_keys(my_username)
elem_passwd.send_keys(my_password + Keys.RETURN)
# In case it need some time to populate the content.
#time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
logginTag = soup.find("a", {"id" : "user_display_name"})
print(logginTag)
driver.close()
```

And here is the output:

```
<a class="header_nick button drop" href="#" id="user_display_name">volatil3_</a>
```

Comment: Interesting. Though it does solve initial problem. How do I get session as I would like to use same session to navigate other pages

Comment: @Volatil3 Selenium is using a fully functional browser, you can just navigate to other pages and it will store the cookie, keep the session..etc as default. Like most browsers do

Comment: Sorry for late response. I just tested it now as I got busy. It's launching FireFox Browser too! Can't I do without that?

Comment: @Volatil3, Of course, you can, it is called something [headless](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/) Selenium or you can just use PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS for Twitch Login, [see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800122/phantomjs-login-to-twitch-through-jquery)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.twitch.tv/login', function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            $("#login_user_login").val("username");
            $("[id='user[password]']").val("password");
            $(".button.primary:first").click(); // click login button
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render("e.png"); // see if anything happens
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000); // 5 seconds
    });
});
```