# PhantomJS - Login to Twitch Through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I am looking for a way to login to twitch through PhantomJS. The code I have now is not working when I look through "e.png"

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.twitch.tv/login', function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            $("login_user_login").val("username");
            $("user[password]").val("password");
            $("button").click(); // click login button
            page.render("e.png"); // see if anything happens
        });
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

I have found a link on how to do it through selenium here:
[Selenium Twitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703924/unable-to-login-twitch-tv-via-script)

HTML (For selectors, per request): https://jsfiddle.net/r8szj7wy/1/

```
<input class="field text med-long" id="login_user_login" name="user[login]" tabindex="8" type="text" />

<input class="field text med-long" id="user[password]" name="user[password]" tabindex="9" type="password" value="" />

<button class="button primary" tabindex="11" type="submit">Log In
```

Comment: What do you mean with *The code I have now is not working when I **look through "e.png"***? There cannot be an e.png file to look at with your code.

Comment: phantom.js renders the code in a picture if you use the render function.

Comment: So you see e.png in the working folder? Then this cannot be produced by the code presented here (see my answer).

Comment: Yes, it pops up with a normal twitch login page with nothing done to it, even after I move it out of the function. Can you post some code in your answer?

Comment: Not sure what your use case is, but Twitch does have an [API](http://dev.twitch.tv/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Impossible render

`page.evaluate()` is the sandboxed page context. It doesn't have access to `page` or any other variables defined outside of it. You need to move the `page.render("e.png")` outside and behind it to see anything.

#### ID selectors

Your selectors are wrong. `login_user_login` and `user[password]` are supposed to be ids, but you're writing the CSS selector as if there are `login_user_login` and `user` elements in the DOM which is not the case. Correct ID selectors would be `#login_user_login` and `[id='user[password]']`. Note that the second one must be written differently than the first one, because it contains `[]` which is reserved for attribute selectors.

#### Page load waiting

And finally, after you click to login, it takes a while, so you need to wait until the page has reloaded. You can use a static timeout using `setTimeout` or a more sophisticated method using [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) from the examples.

Final simple script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.twitch.tv/login', function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            $("#login_user_login").val("username");
            $("[id='user[password]']").val("password");
            $(".button.primary:first").click(); // click login button
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render("e.png"); // see if anything happens
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000); // 5 seconds
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems no matter what I do it says I am using the wrong password, even though I typed in the right one.

Comment: Have you used global variables to do this or did you replace `"password"` with `"yourPassword"`?

Comment: You forgot to add the :first selector, which I didn't realize I needed.